# Having a hard time with callbacks

Tags: javascript, loops, callback

Learning about callbacks and the solution to this problem eludes me.
It should print a number every second counting down until zero. Currently, it logs the numbers from 10 - 0 but all at once and continues in an infinite loop.

Please help me to gain a better understanding of this situation. I have read up on callbacks and have a conceptual understanding but execution is still a bit tricky.

```
var seconds = 0;

var countDown = function(){
    for(var cnt = 10; cnt > 0; cnt--){
        setTimeout(function(x){
            return function(){
                seconds++
                console.log(x);
            };
        }(cnt), seconds * 1000);
    }
}
countDown()
```

Comment: I tried using setInterval() but with similar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your code is working now, it executes a `for` loop with `cnt` going from 10 to 1. This works. On each iteration, it schedules a new function to be run in `seconds * 1000` milliseconds, carefully and properly isolating the value of `cnt` in `x` each time. The problem is that `seconds` is `0`, and it will only be changed once a callback executes; but by the time a callback executes, all of them will already have been scheduled for execution. If you need `seconds * 1000` to vary while you’re still scheduling them all (while the `for` loop is still running), you need to change `seconds` in the loop, rather than inside one of the callbacks.

Comment: That worked. I can see now why it kept looping thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [IIFEs](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to see how they work.  In this situation, you're creating a closure of the value you want to print.  You had the right idea, but your syntax was off.

```
var seconds = 0;

var countDown = function () {
    var cnt = 10;

    // simplify your loop
    while (cnt--) {

        // setTimeout expects a function
        // use an IIFE to capture the current value to log
        setTimeout((function (x) {

            // return the function that setTimeout will execute
            return function (){
                console.log(x + 1);
            };
        }(cnt)), (++seconds) * 1000);
    }
};
countDown();
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add a little explanation as to what was wrong before, and why it works now?

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't create functions within loops and you'd avoid the unary operators.

Comment: The syntax wasn’t really off—after all, it did parse and run, it just did something other than what was expected.